# Iterative printing over parallel lists to print columns in Python

Tags: python, list, collections, printing

I have vsort and vsorta, both lists with equal numbers of items that should be right next to each other (about 250 elements per list). I want to print them as parallel columns, like so:

```
>>> for x,y in vsort,vsorta:
...     print x, y
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
>>>
```

Is there a way around this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
for x, y in zip(vsort, vsorta):
       print x, y
```

`zip` takes some number of lists and makes them into one list of tuples.

Comment: Or `izip` from the `itertools` module (in Python 2.x), which creates a generator instead of a whole new list and thus uses less memory.

Comment: Thanks. Zip worked fine -- I'll try izip if I ever run into this problem again. I wish I knew how all of these doohickeys worked, though...